# Extracting tree object relevant data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have a Javascript object as follows:

```
MainData: Object
 ->SubData: Array[23]
   ->0:Object
       Name : "ABC"
       ID: 1
       ->DataToDisplay :Array[2]
         ->0:Object
           Guid :"18189-90"
           Geo : "USA"
         ->1 : object
           Guid : "234-8089"
           Geo :"UK"
         OtherIrrelevantData : SomeData
         ->Children:Array[20]
           ->0:Object
              Name:"DEF"
              ID:2
              ->DataToDisplay : Array[1]
                ->0:object
                Guid :"18167-90"
                Geo : "Nor"
              ->Children : Array[5]
                ->0:Object 
                   Name : "GHI"
                   ID : 3 
                   ->DataToDisplay :Array[2]
                    ->0:Object
                      Guid :"18189-90"
                      Geo : "Ger"
                    ->1 : object
                      Guid : "234-8089"
                      Geo :"Pol"
                    otherirrelevantData : SomeData
```

My aim is to display only the array "DataToDisplay" in the html page recursively .
For eg: if the control matches **Name:"ABC"**, I should be able to display ,5 Geo names everything under the root **"ABC"**.I need an object with name "ABC" and "DataToDisplay" under it,"DEF" and "GHI" also as well.

And if the data matches name "GHI", I need an object with the name "GHI" and DataToDisplay under it.

I am trying to make use of forach loops for it, but fails when the nodes get added. Any suggestions to extract the data from above information?

Comment: you can show what you came up so far and where it fails

Comment: Do you have to iterate the entire object or are you always looking in the same places?

Comment: This is an example of of what you're trying to do yes? https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ejhxnLt4/

Comment: More code please, if you can show us html and js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tree-node-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-node-utils) can provide what your need. See the 'findNodes' function in this demo: https://linsight.github.io/tree-node-utils/demo/dist/

here is the implementation of `findNodes` in ES6:

```
findNodes(nodes, predicate) {
  let found = [];
  const self = this;
  for (const node of nodes) {
    if (predicate(node)) {
      found = [...found, node];
    }

    if (self.hasChildren(node)) {
      const foundChildren = self.findNodes(node.children, predicate);
      found = [...found, ...foundChildren];
    }
   }

   return found;
  };
```

What it does is:

1. Loop through all root nodes;
2. For each of them, test the root node using a callback function `predicate`
3. Add to the result array if callback function passes
4. If the node has children data, do the same for all the children recursively
5. return the result.

In your case, your `predicate` function is like:

`function canDisplay(node){
   return node.Name === 'ABC';
}`